Does there exists an open neighbourhood U of the support A of a sub-complex of a triangulation of X that retracts to A?
Let $X$ be a topological space and $Z$ a closed subset of $X$, such that
there exists a triangulation of $X$ in which $Z$ appears as the support of
a sub-complex.
For retract  and deformation retract, we adopt the standard definitions: If $i: A \subset M$ is the inclusion and $r: M \rightarrow A$ is a continuous map which restricts to the identity on $A$, then $r$ is called a retraction of $M$ onto $A$;  If in addition $i \circ r: M \rightarrow M$ is homotopic to the identity on $M$, then $r$ is said to be a deformation retraction of $M$ onto $A$.
Question: Does there exist an open neighbourhood $U$ of $Z$ that retracts onto $Z$? If so,
does there exist an open neighbourhood $V$ of $Z$ that  deformation retracts onto $Z$?

Fairly certain you're looking for the open star of the subcomplex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex#Closure,_star,_and_link. Since you want it in the space X, push the open star of the subcomplex for Z through the triangulation homeomorphism. Or perhaps you want to take a subdivision or two. Whatever. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118280/constructing-a-deformation-neighborhood
